# Why does $_SESSION stop working when I restart web server?

Tags: php, html, session

I apologise if this is a silly question but I am developing an e commerce website and am trying to use the $_SESSION to store the shopping cart items in an array. My code is working perfectly however when we reboot the web server the $_SESSION array stops storing values.

This is how we are appending to the $_SESSION array and this works but as soon as the web server is restarted, it doesn't seem to store the data or load it.

```
<?php
session_start();

$ProductID = $_GET['ProductID'];
$quantity = $_GET['Quantity']; 

if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $ProductID);

?>
```

In other words, before the restart I was able to successfully use Session... after the restart I am not able to store any values in session at all (it just won't store or load values).

Thanks for your help.....

Comment: this will strongly depend on the setup, in particular how `session.save_handler` is configured (in other words: where the session data is actually stored. files,db,memcache,...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies, or you can save shopping cart items on db. Cookies will be available even after restart, as long as user will not clear them.

Comment: It's not the answer. Here the questioner wants to know if his server has a problem with storing sessions.